# How to substring by searching the whole word first?

Tags: java, substring

How can I substring a string if I have to search for a specific word in a string first which will become the start point of substring?

For example, I have a url like this `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=fn45T6k5JzA&cpn=SS3mhNaZwOE7WnYl&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_US&sts=15956&width=500&height=400&c=web&cver=html5` and I need to substring video ID from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try regular expressions

[Here's some information on using regular expressions in java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

The following regular expression:

```
video_id=(.*?)&
```

should do it.

http://rubular.com/r/d24wDwk2wv

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title explicitly:

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("word") + "word".length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String url="http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=fn45T6k5JzA&cpn=SS3mhNaZwOE7WnYl&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_US&sts=15956&width=500&height=400&c=web&cver=html5";
String subData=url.substring(url.indexOf("video_id=")+"video_id=".length(),url.indexOf("&",url.indexOf("video_id="))); // outputs fn45T6k5JzA
```

Have a look at different variations `string#indexOf` method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would use `String.indexOf(String toIndex)` and this will give the index of the first character in the substring. If you do:

```
 String video = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=fn45T6k5JzA&cpn=SS3mhNaZwOE7WnYl&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_US&sts=15956&width=500&height=400&c=web&cver=html5";
 String data = video.substring(video.indexOf("video_id=") + 9);
```

This should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring from between posithon after `video_id=` and its next `&`

```
String link = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=fn45T6k5JzA&cpn=SS3mhNaZwOE7WnYl&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_US&sts=15956&width=500&height=400&c=web&cver=html5";

int start = link.indexOf("video_id") + "video_id".length() + 1; // +1 to include position of `=`
int end = link.indexOf("&", start);
String value = link.substring(start, end);

System.out.println(value);
```

output: `fn45T6k5JzA`

---

Other, probably more readable way would be using [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) from [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

```
String link = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=fn45T6k5JzA&cpn=SS3mhNaZwOE7WnYl&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_US&sts=15956&width=500&height=400&c=web&cver=html5";

List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(link,
        Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

for (NameValuePair nvp : parameters) {
    if (nvp.getName().equals("video_id"))
        System.out.println(nvp.getValue());
}
```

output: `fn45T6k5JzA`